# Calcular área do círculo

Tags: java

Estou com dificuldades para escreve esse exercício na Linguagem *Java*, usando a IDE *Eclipse*:

> Desenvolver um programa para calcular a área do círculo.

Nesse exercício preciso atribuir ao Pi (π) o valor de 3,1416,
sendo que o cálculo da área é igual ao Pi(π), multiplicado pelo raio elevado ao quadrado!

Como devo escrever os "comandos" na Linguagem Java? Comecei o curso esse mês, ou seja só consigo usar o básico.

Obs: Consigo digitar o valor do raio, porém quando dou ENTER o programa não roda!

**Meu código:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double raio;
        double area;
        final double PI = 3.1416;

       System.out.println("Escreva o valor do raio");
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       raio = scan.nextFloat();
       area = scan.nextFloat();


       area  = PI* (raio*raio);

       System.out.print("O valor da area é " + area);  
       System.out.print(area);
       scan.close();
```

Comment: Oi Carol quando você fala que não "roda" apresenta algum erro no console do ecplise ou simplesmente para de funcionar ?

Comment: Viktor Hugo -  eu clico em RUN ,ele me pede para digitar o Raio,eu digito e depois nada ocorre.. ele não calcula a area

Comment: Você está a pedir dois valores, o `raio` e a `area`, logo o programa está a espera que meta os 2

Comment: Isac, então tenho que alem de digitar o valor do Raio digitar o Pi que no meu caso é : 3.1416?

Comment: Reverti as alterações pois seu código está mal indentado na pergunta.

Comment: Valdeir Psr  - desculpa a minha "burrice" o que esta errado? pois quero editar para ficar certinho kk

Comment: Não tinha nada errado, como Iscac falou... depois que você digitou o raio ele pedoiu paravocê digitar o valor da area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que o seu código não está terminando de rodar porque você tem mais um comando pedindo que insira um número `area = scan.nextFloat();` embora não haja um `System.out.print(Escreva o valor da área)`. Mesmo porque a área será calculada, não é mesmo?

O corpo do método que modifiquei é:

```
double raio;
double area;
final double PI = 3.1416;

System.out.println("Escreva o valor do raio");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
raio = scan.nextFloat();

area  = PI* Math.pow(raio, 2);

System.out.print("O valor da area é " + area);  
scan.close();
```

Com resultado (no NetBeans):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível ao invés de declarar `final double PI = 3.1416;`, não declarar variável alguma e usar:

`area = Math.PI * Math.pow(raio, 2);`

Fiquei pensando sobre a formatação do número ao final, e gostaria de fazer a seguinte sugestão:

`System.out.printf("O valor da area é %,.2f \n", area);`

`System.out.printf` imprime o texto formatado, em que `%` indica onde incluir o valor da variável indicada após a vírgula. `%,.2f` significa formate o valor da variável com uma vírgula como separador e 2 casas decimais. Para mudar para 4 casas decimais, por exemplo, basta usar `%,.4f` ao invés de `%,.2f`. O `\n` ao final é apenas para incluir uma linha ao final do código rodar. Com essa alteração, o resultado fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu uso o Eclipse ,será que os códigos rodam igual no NetBeans?

Comment: Deveria, posto que Eclipse e NetBeans são apenas um ambiente de desenvolvimento, mas a linguagem continua a mesma. A forma de organização de aplicações maiores, com varias classes etc, será um pouco diferente, mas o código que roda em um deve rodar no outro sem necessidade de alterações.

Answer (score 7):

1. Você não precisa do `import java.io.IOException;`.
2. Não use o `close` no `Scanner`.
3. Você não deve ler a área do `Scanner`. Você deve calcular ela a partir do raio.
4. A biblioteca padrão já inclui `Math.PI`, e portanto você não precisa redefinir isso por fora.
5. Você está escrevendo a área duas vezes no `System.out.print`. Só precisa fazer isso uma vez.
6. Você provavelmente vai querer usar `System.out.println` ao invés de `System.out.print`. Facilita na hora de juntar isso com outras coisas que você fizer depois.

Seu código fica assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Exercicio3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Escreva o valor do raio");
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       double raio = scan.nextFloat();
       double area = Math.PI * raio * raio;

       System.out.println("O valor da area é " + area);
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/1I2vC5)

Answer (score 2):

Olhando seu código, algumas sugestões.

```
double raio = 0;
/* inicialize variaveis que for utilizar em cálculos */
double area = 0;
final double PI = 3.1416;
```

Ao solicitar dados do usuário:

```
// Não faz sentido você solicitar a àrea pois será calculada
area = scan.nextFloat();
```

Agora voltando ao problema, depois que vocês digita o valor do raio o cursor pula a linha solicitando o valor da area também por isso dá a impressão de não acontecer nada. Apenas remova esta linha `area = scan.nextFloat();`

Comment: vou tentar aqui então e ver se da certo

Answer (score 2):

Tem alguns pontos que você deve rever:

1 - O `import java.io.IOException;` não é necessário nesse código 
 2 - Você pode facilitar a criação de variáveis colocando-as em uma mesma linha e separando por "," `double raio, area;` 
 3 - Não use o `close();` no Scanner 
 4 - Como você definiu as variáveis como double, é recomendável que você use `scan.nextDouble()` ao invés de `scan.nextFloat()`
 5 - Por fim, dê uma olhada nas classes Math do Java, assim você pode realizar algumas operções de maneira mais fácil, por exemplo, ao invés de `area = pi * (raio * raio);` use `area = pi * (Math.pow(raio, 2));`

Vou deixar abaixo um código que eu faria e acho ser a maneira mais fácil de resolver seu problema

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double raio, area;

        System.out.println("Escreva o valor do raio:");
        raio = scan.nextDouble();

        area = 3.1416 * (Math.pow(raio, 2));

        System.out.println("O valor da area eh:" + area);

    }
}
```